# JADE multi array

Tags: html, pug

I have so many arrays and want to use it

```
- list = ['index1', 'index2', 'index3'];
- list2 = ['list2', 'list21', 'list22'];
each item in list
  div #{item}
    each item2 in list2
      span #{item2}
```

but it compiled this:

```
index1list2list21list22
index2list2list21list22
index3list2list21list22
```

I want this result:

```
index1list2
index2list21
index3list22
```

Are any solution for this? Can jade do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want to iterate through `list` and get the element at the same index in `list2`.

What you probably want to do is something like the following:

```
- list = ['index1', 'index2', 'index3'];
- list2 = ['list2', 'list21', 'list22'];
each item, index in list
  div #{item}
    span #{item2[index]}
```

This will give you

```
index1list2
index2list21
index3list22
```

You'll want to ensure that `list.length = list2.length` and handle the case where they aren't (more specifically, when `list.length > list2.length`). Otherwise, you'll likely get something like the following:

```
- list = ['index1', 'index2', 'index3', 'index4'];
- list2 = ['list2', 'list21', 'list22'];
each item, index in list
  div #{item}
    span #{item2[index]}
```

Result:

```
index1list2
index2list21
index3list22
index4undefined
```